# add navigation controller to webview created programmatically swift 3

Tags: webview, swift3, uinavigationcontroller

I have this code that creates a webView:

```
var webV:UIWebView = UIWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height))
```

I have the WebView did start like so:

```
func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

I have embedded a navigation controller on the view controller, which I didn't want to do, because I only want the navigation to show on the webview, but oh well.

The problem is that now the navigation conroller cuts off the top portion of the webview. I know I can adjust the webview down, but is that what I'm supposed to do? I feel like it should be easier to create a webview with a navigation controller.

Any help would be appreciated. Yes I have looking through stack overflow, however everyone else is using a viewcontroller to present the webview whereas I create the webview

Answer (score 0):

You create the `UIWebView` with `UIScreen.main.bounds` width and height. That means that your web view will take up the entire screen in terms of size. However, you would have other elements on screen such as the status bar, the navigation bar (and, for example, if you have a tab bar, the tab bar at the bottom) which would take up some of the screen space.

So, what you should really do is set up layout constraints so that your web view makes use of the top and bottom layout guides so that your web view appears in the visible area.

If you are not sure of how to do autolayout constraints via code, [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/125718/coding-auto-layout) might help.

Alternatively, you can also take the bounds of the view to which you are adding your webview to set the size for your web view, but adjust the height (and the top position) to allow for the navigation bar.